# how to apply a class selector an element?

Tags: html, css

write a rule for a class selector named emphasis.set the color property to blue and the background-color property to yellow.In the document apply the emphasis class to the  element within the paragraph.

So far I have written the class sector with the name emphasis but i dont know how to apply it with in the paragraph.

```
in style
.emphasis {
color:blue;
background-color: yellow; }

 <p>For chapter 4 of css.This is a on <em>project</em>.This
shows a paragraph.This shows a <span class="emphasis">paragraph</span>.This shows a paragraph.This shows a paragraph.This shows a paragraph.This shows
a paragraph.This shows a paragraph.This shows a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Can you share what you have written so far?

Comment: i have added the code of what i have so far

Comment: So where do you want to apply the class? Currently it applies to that whole `<p>` element. Use `<span>` to target a specific area.

Comment: i added it to the word paragraph.

Comment: Cool, so is that your issue? Is it solved?

Comment: so it wants me to apply the emphasis class to the <em> element within the paragraph so can it be any word or the word thats highlighted which is the word paragraph would i apply the <em>